# How can I make a theme region expand height to fit content of several blocks, pushing all following region content down?

Tags: theming, blocks

After a long hiatus from Drupal work, I now need to meet a request to modify a Drupal 7 site. In the existing theme I need one more full-width theme region than what's available. (At one point I had made a custom theme to do just that, but now having too many problems getting the same previously working one to work again.)

The item to be inserted is a slideshow view block. Lacking the ideal extra region, I tried inserting into the Menu Region, below the actual menu block. It displays fully. But, the height of this new block does not expand the total height of the region, thus the regions below it do not get pushed down as needed. The slideshow view block just overlaps and obscures some of what's below it.

I can't find a CSS selector and property to make this work. Can you suggest a path for solving this? Or, is the attempt to make this work in a Menu Region just not going to be workable?

Comment: The standard behavior for blocks is to push content down, so if that's not happening, there is probably some bad CSS somewhere, most likely in your theme (are you using one of the core themes? if not, test with one; they should not have this problem) or in the CSS that is getting added for the slideshow.

Comment: Later I was able to find a selector to solve the problem. Possibly not the best, most efficient solution but it works in browser tests so far. That was after also getting a modified theme with added region, named "displayarea" to work. 
#displayarea > div {
height: 462px;
}